# Why does fa-rotate-90 icons appear blurry in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

This image is a screenshot from Font Awesome [examples](http://fontawesome.io/examples/)

[image: blurry 90 & 270]

On my screen (and I even rotated in Paint to make sure it really was blurry and not just some magic) the 90 and 270 degree rotations appear blurry. The vertical and horizontal flips are fine. My question is **why**? What is it about either Chrome, or the Font Awesome mechanism that causes this to happen?

Naturally, thing are **much** worse in IE 9

[image: IE loves rendering]

Comment: cleartype? anti-aliasing done for LCDs will is generally done horizontally, and rotating that horizontal aliasing into a vertical orientation will look like crap.

Comment: In my chrome they don't look AS bad, but they're certainly not as crisp as normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The font-awesome CSS define a CSS rule that causes this issue.

```
.fa {
    line-height: 1;
}
```

After removing this rule, the icon display very well.

Comment: Chuck norris can help IE ;)